# Failing to remove all $ in strings in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string

I'm trying to remove unnecessary values in the strings in my dataframe so I can make them integers and do some math logic on them. The commas, and upward arrows are removed as desired but I can't seem to remove $ from my dataframe. But I have removed it successfully from row two which is a very odd anomoly.

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
req = Request('https://smallcaps.com.au/director-transactions/'
              , headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
trades = urlopen(req).read()
df = pd.read_html(trades)[0]
del df['Director'],df['Company']

print(df.head(5))

df['Value'] = df['Value'].replace(['↑','$',','],'',regex=True)

print("############################")
print(df.head(5))
```

Results:
Unchanged df:

```
        Date Code     Value
0  27/4/2022  ESR   ↑$1,075
1  27/4/2022  LNY  ↑126,750
2  26/4/2022  FGX  ↑$13,363
3  26/4/2022  CDM  ↑$25,110
4  26/4/2022  TEK  ↑$35,384
    ############################
```

Signs removed but failed to remove all dollar signs:

```
        Date Code   Value
0  27/4/2022  ESR   $1075
1  27/4/2022  LNY  126750
2  26/4/2022  FGX  $13363
3  26/4/2022  CDM  $25110
4  26/4/2022  TEK  $35384

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: row 2 doesn't contain $ in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

`$` sign has special meaning in regex, you need to escape it

```py
df['Value'] = df['Value'].replace(['↑','\$',','], '', regex=True)
```

```
print(df)

        Date Code   Value
0  27/4/2022  ESR    1075
1  27/4/2022  LNY  126750
2  26/4/2022  FGX   13363
3  26/4/2022  CDM   25110
4  26/4/2022  TEK   35384
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `|` to separate the multiple chars you want to replace. And escape `$` with `\$`.

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].str.replace('↑|,|\$', '')

In [82]: df.head()
Out[82]: 
        Date Code    Value
0  27/4/2022  ESR    1075
1  27/4/2022  LNY  126750
2  26/4/2022  FGX   13363
3  26/4/2022  CDM   25110
4  26/4/2022  TEK   35384
```

Comment: You should also replace the "," as OP mentions he wants to work with integers.

Comment: @not_speshal Removed the comma as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could `replace` the commas that occur within the number and then extract the whole number:

```
df["Value"] = df['Value'].str.replace(",","",regex=True).str.extract("(\d+)").astype(int)

>>> df
        Date Code   Value
0  27/4/2022  ESR    1075
1  27/4/2022  LNY  126750
2  26/4/2022  FGX   13363
3  26/4/2022  CDM   25110
4  26/4/2022  TEK   35384
```

Alternatively, replace all the unnecessary characters:

```
df["Value"] = df['Value'].str.replace('↑|↓|\$|,|', '', regex=True).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to work with numbers, the ideal is probably to get rid of everything but the numbers and convert to numeric.

```
df['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Value'].str.replace(r'\D', '', regex=True))
```

If you have floats, use `r'[^\d\.]'` in place of `r'\D'`.
output:

```
        Date Code   Value
0  27/4/2022  ESR    1075
1  27/4/2022  LNY  126750
2  26/4/2022  FGX   13363
3  26/4/2022  CDM   25110
4  26/4/2022  TEK   35384
```